# Adobe Extended Script: Any way to localize the promt confirm()? Yes and No should be translated to "Ja" und Nein"

Tags: photoshop-scripting, extended-scripting

```
if (!inddLastest.exists) {
    doc.save(inddLastest);
  } else {
    //btnText = { en: "Yes", de: "Ja", fr: "Oui" }; b1 = w.add ("button", undefined, localize (btnText));
    var res = confirm("Die InDesign-Datei existiert bereits. \rSoll sie überschrieben werden?", true, "Problem");
    // if the user hits no, stop the script
    if (res !== true) {
      return; //get out of this function
    } else {
      doc.save(inddLastest); //yes, overwrite
    }
  }
```

Comment: maybe try to put `$.localize = true;` in the beginning of your script?

Comment: In the docs it's only in combination with an alert: https://wwwimages2.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/scripting/pdfs/javascript_tools_guide.pdf Page 227 - but how do I get into these Buttons? - localize works with a custom UI very well but this is a standard-element, hmm